# Laravel validation returns to null using value="{{ old(firstname) }}" and still throw errorbag when i already typed data on textfield

Tags: php, laravel

What am I missing here, I am a newbie in Laravel and tried crash course on youtube, when I click the register button previous data returns to null, and the error required messages show up. Tried reading and looking for a solution on the internet came up with nothing. I couldn't figure out what I am missing or what I am doing wrong here.

**Register.blade.php**

```
<div class="col-lg-auto justify-content-center">
                    @if ($errors->any())
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <ul>
                                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                 @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                <form action="{{route('register')}}" method="post">
                    @csrf 
                        <h1>Register</h1>

                        <div>
                            <input type="text" id='firstname' placeholder="First Name" value="{{ old('firstname') }}"> 
                            <input type="text" id='lastname' placeholder="Last Name" value="{{ old('lastname') }}">
                            {{--<div class="error">
                                @error('firstname')
                                 {{ $message }}   
                                @enderror
                            </div>--}}
                        </div>
```

..........................................

**PageController.php** this is the controller page

```
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;//validation ito for request


class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('pages.index');
    }
    public function register(){
        return view('auth.register');
    }


    public function store(Request $request) {
        
        $this->validate($request, [
            'firstname' => 'required|max:20',
            'lastname' => 'required|max:20',
            'address' => 'required|max:100',
            'barangay' => 'required|max:100',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:35',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed',
            ]);
            dd('store');
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the name of your inputs,
Try to add the name attribute for each inputs

like the example below :

```
<input 
type="text" 
name="firstname" // add this attribute
id='firstname' 
placeholder="First Name" 
value="{{ old('firstname') }}"
>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice this.